# Not cache a specific part of a Firebase database in Android at all

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my use-case, I do not want to cache a specific part of the Firebase Database at all in my Android app.

I have tried the following things:

1)   This change is made in the Application class of my app.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("point-To-Place-I-don't-wanna-cache").keepSynced(false);
```

2) Removed `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled();`from the application class.
Put `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("point-To-Place-I-don't-wanna-cache").keepSynced(false);`in the activity before database access.

3) A few more combinations of the above commands.

Nothing seemed to work.

Comment: The answer is unfortunately that this is not possible. But it sound like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by excluding a certain part from the disk cache? Maybe there's another way to accomplish that same goal.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setPersistenceEnabled(true)`, all data that the client recently received is cached to disk.

There is no way to exclude certain nodes from that disk persistence.

Comment: But I have mentioned setPersistenceEnabled(false) in my code. This should not cache anything and I'm still fine with it. But still data is being cached and that seems problematic.

Comment: I've never heard of data being cached to disk when that cache was disabled (as it is by default). Did you have disk caching enabled at some point? If so, the disk cache may still contain data from that time. Uninstall/reinstall the app to get rid of this. If that doesn't help: how did you determine that data is being cached?

Comment: Yes I did have disk cache enabled at some point. I have made sure that I uninstalled the app everytime I tested it. I check it by going to : App Info -> Storage and check the cache space used (which turns out to be non-zero and sometimes double-digits). Moreover, if I remove the app from recent tasks, turn off the internet and launch the app, the data is loading and my views are getting populated. That's how I get to know data is cached locally. @Frank

Comment: The non-zero space makes it seem like the app wasn't completely deleted. I'm not sure how that happened, but if the remaining file is indeed the Firebase client's disk cache, it would explain the behavior you're seeing. But I'm not sure if the client should be loading the disk cache at all: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/00d46269f1ef9ce0f1dd69ab727137a84332d85c/firebase-database/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/database/core/Context.java#L155

Comment: Hey @Frank, I am absolutely certain that I completely deleted the app.I have uninstalled for all users in my Android device. In fact, with my increased usage of the newly installed app, the cache size increases ( indicating that it wasn't the previously stored cache, as it would have been constant).

Comment: Also @Frank, when I tried to put 
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceCacheSizeBytes(0) 
, the app stops immediately whilst launching.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I want to stop database from storing some parts of database for security reasons because i don't want anyone to access that data outside the app. Is there a way i can achieve this? At least manually deleting some of data when user exits the application.